# Add children to UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a user control and now I would like to be able to set it up so I can add children to each instance of it.

This is how it's laid out:

[image]

The red boxes are panels that I'd like to be able to add children to. The idea is that I use this control in my winforms app, and from there drag and drop new controls into the red parent container.

How do I do this?

Comment: in the user control you code the functionality. eg. `buttonPanel.Items.Add(someButton);` or do you expect us to make the drag and drop haha

Comment: Controls have collection of child controls `Items` , this link will be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: To make Drag'n'Drop it's easily to see some tutorials.

Comment: where da code at

Comment: What do you mean "I can add children to each instance"? Do you want to use it as a container control in designer? Or at runtime, programmatically?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I went out before I posed this, didn't expect this many replies so soon.

Comment: @EpicKip I just want to know if it's possible to drag items from the toolbox into one of the red areas to have it become a child of the user control.

Comment: @KamikyIT Sorry, I just started C# so maybe I don't know the right terminology to find what I'm looking for, but I searched for a while about this topic and only found tutorials for WPF. Thank you for the link though.

Comment: @Glubs I just made it in the designer, I haven't written much code for it.

Comment: @taffer Both ideally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know if it's possible to drag items from the toolbox into one of the red areas to have it become a child of the user control.

Yes, it is possible:

```
[Designer(typeof(MyUserControlDesigner))]
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
}
```

And you have to implement a designer class. This is how you can add controls to the inner `Content` panel at design time (assuming that the panel is exposed as a public `PanelContent` property):

```
internal sealed class MyUserControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    IDesignerHost designerHost;

    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);
        base.AutoResizeHandles = true;
        base.EnableDesignMode(((MyUserControl)component).PanelContent, "ContentPanel");
        designerHost = (IDesignerHost)component.Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
    }

    public override bool CanParent(Control control)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override System.Collections.ICollection AssociatedComponents
    {
        get
        {
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
            foreach (Control control in ((MyUserControl)Control).PanelContent.Controls)
            {
                list.Add(control);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    protected override Control GetParentForComponent(IComponent component)
    {
        return ((MyUserControl)Control).PanelContent;
    }

    public override int NumberOfInternalControlDesigners()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override ControlDesigner InternalControlDesigner(int internalControlIndex)
    {
        Control panel = ((MyUserControl)Control).PanelContent;
        switch (internalControlIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return this.designerHost.GetDesigner(panel) as ControlDesigner;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    protected override IComponent[] CreateToolCore(ToolboxItem tool, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool hasLocation, bool hasSize)
    {
        ParentControlDesigner panelDesigner = this.designerHost.GetDesigner(((MyUserControl)Control).PanelContent) as ParentControlDesigner;
        InvokeCreateTool(panelDesigner, tool);
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to expose multiple hosts you can modify `NumberOfInternalControlDesigners` and `InternalControlDesigner` methods. However, it never really worked for me. You can decide by the component to add, which parent should be used (see `GetParentForComponent`) but it means for example that buttons are always added to the buttons panel. I suggest to offer the content panel only as parent and use some public properties for manipulating the buttons panel instead.

Comment: Thanks. I got this working just for the content area, but getting both to work didn't happen, like you said. I decided to just do the entire thing in code instead. I think it will take longer, but I don't have the time to read the entire docs about design time support right now. Will keep this in mind for the future though, thanks you.